# String function - replace instances of a character if they are between two other characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I ran a massive SQL query that I don't want to run again and saved the results as a csv.  I am doing some processing in a C# console app that adds each record to a storage table.  Unfortunately, I messed up and did not remove ','s from the results, and there are some objects serialized in JSON in this data which contain ','.

I am already looping through all this data, and so that my columns correctly line up I would just like to temporarily convert ',' to say ';', but only if it is between curly braces in the string.  For example:

```
ID,InputModel,Type
1,{"address":"11th street"},true
2,{"address":"11th street, new york"},true
```

My code is as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < allLines.Length; j++)
{                    
    string line = allLines[j];
    // would like to replace ',' with ';' if between curly braces
    string[] data = line.Split(',');
    myInsertMethod(data);
}
```

Desired result:

```
ID,InputModel,Type
1,{"address":"11th street"},true
2,{"address":"11th street; new york"},true
```

Comment: Just spent a while trying to construct a match only to be thwarted by your sample data - I assume the `)` in the 3rd line should be `}`?

Comment: Yes!  Sorry :( I have updated it!

Comment: No worries, I was completely stumped why it wasn't working until I spotted that :)  You have an answer now though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match a comma inside curly braces using the following regex:

```
(?<=\{[^}]*),(?=[^}]*\})
```

You can replace it with a semi-colon:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\{[^}]*),(?=[^}]*\})");
var result = rgx.Replace("{word, word}, {word, word}", ";");
```

Result: `{word; word}, {word; word}`

Your code:

```
private static readonly Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\{[^}]*),(?=[^}]*\})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...
for (int j = 0; j < allLines.Length; j++)
{                    
    var line = allLines[j];
    var data = rgx.Replace(line, ";").Split(',');
    myInsertMethod(data);
}
```

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

Comment: Great, would you perhaps write a complete code. Thank you

Comment: Just remember to declare the regex object as a static readonly field and use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag. Then, use it in the `for` loop.